# Parameter in http.put is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

Im trying to update an object in my backend. I have created this backend methode

```
  // PUT: api/Appointment/5
        /// <summary>
        /// Modifies an appointment
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="appointmentId">id of the appointment to be modified</param>
        /// <param name="start">Start of appointment</param>
        /// <param name="end">End of appointment</param>
        [HttpPut("{appointmentId}")]
        public IActionResult PutAppointment(int appointmentId, string start)
        {
            if(start == null) {
                Console.WriteLine("null");
            }
```

But my start paramater that i return from my angular app is alway null.
This is my angular methode:

```
updateAppointment(
    appointmentId:number, start: string
  ): Observable<any>{
    console.log(start);

    const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('start', start);

    return this.http.put(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/appointment/${appointmentId}`,
      {params},
      { responseType: "text"})
  }
```

I tried multiple things, but all of them return start with a null value. I log it to the console in my angular app and there it gives the right value of the string, but in my backend (asp net) it always is null.

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: Are the ```HttpParams``` the body? You'll have to use ```[FromBody] string start``` in that case.

Comment: The second parameter of the [put](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put) request should be the body of the request. The query params should be a part of the third parameter.